# Extra space at the bottom of the view controller?

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I am using a storyboard with a custom tab bar controller.

When view controllers are added through the storyboard references, with a container(embedded) view, it creates an extra space at the bottom of the view controller, ie just above the tab bar.

The dimension of the space seems to be the same as that of the tab bar height. Is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: can you show your constraints for this vc

Comment: I think you can click some option in the IB to set it below the tab bar.

Comment: i have faced this issue when I was presenting uiimagecontroller over it... are you presenting anything over the viewcontrollers, or above the child view controllers?

Comment: if you are presenting anything use this - <your controller>.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext

Comment: @iOSDeveloper Like I am presenting a view controller as a storyboard reference.

Comment: @iOSDeveloper And i am displaying it with a container view

Comment: @dahiya_boy I have added the screenshot for constraints

Comment: Debug the app and get it to the screen where the view is not quite touching the bottom and then click the "View Hierarchy" button. this will allow you to see whether it is the container view or the view within the container view that is too short. Let me know which element is too short

Comment: Make sure **Extend Edges Under Opaque Bars** and **Under Bottom Bars** are selected for UIViewController in storyboard

Comment: @fAiSaL Your constraints are perfect. Please debug run time view hierarchy and check what is there above the tab bar

Comment: @Nitish I tried that earlier, but have no effect.

Comment: @Nitish You are right. I did use it for the parent view controller but forgot it for the child one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the following in storyboard :
**Extend Edges**
1. *Under Opaque Bars*
2. *Under Bottom Bars*

[image]